# How to insert spaces before Macros Definition by clang-format?

Tags: c++, c

Thanks to everyone who obvious this title!
I have read the article from clang-format style options but still have not found the things about insert space before macros.
These are my favorite format styles about macros definition.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ5Vn.png)

By reading clang-format style options, I have known about the 'AlignConsecutiveMacros' option. Using it can help me to get a beautiful style window but still not kick my heart.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oLoZ.png)

As you can see, if I use the short macro name, my window may look like the following pic.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHaYz.png)

So, are there some ways to help clang-format achieve this question?

Comment: I want to achieve multiple spaces before the macro name.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't post screenshots of text, copy it verbatim and format it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.